# sending object on bootstrap modal close

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

In my angular 6 project I have a bootstrap modal and I want to pass an object to the modal container component on close!
how can  I do that on button click?

```
  <button (click)="activeModal.close()">Ok</button>
```

Comment: are you using `bootstrap` or `ng-bootstrap` or `ngx-bootstrap`? This is pretty essential to the question, since they work completely differently codewise ;)

Answer (score 0):

create a variable `myObj: Object;`;

and then `<button (click)="activeModal.close(); myObj = someObj">Ok</button>`

or, if more complex you can try

```
<button (click)="activeModal.close(); onClose()">Ok</button>
```

and then create an onClose() method.

Comment: I know this I wanna know how to pass the object to the modal parent component

Comment: This should not help if user close modal without clicking blank page or esc key.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to pass an object from a child to a parent?

and yeah, this is only emitted on click. I think I misunderstood the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should listen modal events to achieve this, [Bootstrap JS Modal Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_hidden&stacked=h) is what you need.

This is javascript example of "hidden.bs.modal" event:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
  //you should use this part
  $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){ 
    alert('The modal is now hidden.');
  });
});
</script>
```

The alert is fired when modal is closed, so it means that you can call a function to push object into your modal content. Hope it helps.